# Has the 1524 Lay Subsidy for Cambridgeshire (UK) been transcribed and published?

Tags: england, 16th-century, taxation-records, cambridgeshire

Has the 1524 Lay Subsidy for Cambridgeshire (UK) been transcribed and published?

If so, where can I find a copy?

National Archives and County Records Office sources aren't showing any holdings

Answer (score 6):

The majority of original records for the lay subsidies are archived at The National Archives, not the local archives. For Cambridgeshire you will find the majority of c.1524 subsidy rolls in [E 179/81](http://discovery.nationalarchives.gov.uk/results/r?_q=E179%2F81). I prefer to look at what's available in the [E 179 Database](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/e179/searchresults.asp?page=1&confirmedplace=Cambridgeshire&slctdoctypeid=&txtplace=cambridgeshire&formid=8&chkplace=&chktaxselection=2&chkdocumentselection=1&txtdocumentfromyear=1520&txtdocumenttoyear=1530&linkback=%2Fe179%2Fsearch%2Easp&targetpage=searchresults%2Easp) on TNA website. You need to browse through the records to see if particular hundreds or localities of interest are available.

The records clearly exist for parts of Cambridgeshire, and while I cannot be sure how complete they are, the analysis performed by John Lee suggests they are quite complete (see [Tracing regional and local changes in population and wealth during the later middle ages using taxation records: Cambridgeshire, 1334-1563](http://www.localpopulationstudies.org.uk/PDF/LPS69/LPS69_2002_32-50.pdf)). I can find no evidence that they have ever been transcribed or indexed online for Cambridgeshire. A search of [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/search?q=cambridgeshire%20lay%20subsidy&qt=results_page) shows that much earlier subsidy lists (1225, 1327) have been transcribed, however nothing comes up for the year of interest.

If there is a specific location of interest, you could obtain a quote from TNA for getting a copy. Fortunately the subsidies have been microfilmed by FamilySearch for the whole country, so it is likely much less expensive to order the film of interest and view it at your local FHC. See [Records of the Exchequer and its related bodies with those of the Office of First Fruits and Tenths, and the Court of Augmentations [hearth taxes and other subsidy taxes] : King's remembrancer, particulars of account and other records relating to lay and clerical taxation, 1272-1678](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/988765) (particularly films 2228641-2228643 will be of interest). I think this is the next best thing to having them published in book form.

Answer (score 2):

[Medieval source material on the internet: Taxation and other lists](http://www.medievalgenealogy.org.uk/sources/tax.shtml) is always my starting point to locate records such as this; there is no indication that the Cambridgeshire Lay Subsidy is online.

Further, a search for "lay subsidy" at [Cambridgeshire Archives Catalogue](http://calm.cambridgeshire.gov.uk/calmview/) does not hold out much hope that the document(s) survived to be transcribed or published.

Comment: Thank you for the link to Medieval on Line. As you say, no help in this particular case but plenty of other sources should I want to come at the problem from another angle.  Hey, stackexchange really works!